# How can filter orders made after a certain date in liquid/ Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

```
{% for orders in checkout.customer.orders %}
//count the orders 
{% endfor %}
```

I need to count orders made only after a certain date?
How can I do this in Liquid / Shopify?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Orders have a `created_at` date that you can output in various formats using the [Liquid date filter](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/additional-filters#date) — you would loop thru the Orders as above and compare that with whatever the "threshold date" in question is, using unix-format dates for comparison:

```
{% assign ordersThresholdUnix = '2019-01-01' | date: '%s' %}
{% assign ordersCount = 0 %}
{% for orders in checkout.customer.orders %}
  {% assign orderDateUnix =  order.created_at | date: '%s' %}
  {% if orderDateUnix > ordersThresholdUnix %}
    {% assign ordersCount = 0 %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can then output `{{ ordersCount }}`.

**Note:** that I don't think Shopify will allow you to paginate further back than 50 Orders.